# Lightning - Tab

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I have few lightning components created, but when I tried to create the lightning tab, its not showing available component to create, like the way we do VF tabs, any help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your component must implement the appHostable interface.  Then it will be available when creating a lightning tab.

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
```

See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_add_cmp_salesforce1.htm

Comment: I was just going to say that.